# Getting an "ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PostsController#show " out of nowhere

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

Okay, so I am trying to display index.html, and RoR is showing me something is up with... def show in posts_controller... Okay?

So the index.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <div class="post_wrapper">
        <h2 class="title"><%= link_to post.title, post%></h2>
        <p class="date"><%= time_ago_in_words(post.created_at)%></p>
    </div>
    <% end %>
</body>
</html>
```

posts_controller.rb

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @posts = Post.all.order('created_at DESC')
    end

    def new
    end

    def create
        @post = Post.new(post_params)
        @post.save

        redirect_to @post
    end
    def show
        @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end
    private

        def post_params
            params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body)
        end    
end
```

My guess was that it's because there was no attribute such as ID, so I changed `params[:id]` to `params[:title]` and still got the same error.

Can you please explain what's wrong and what needs to be fixed?

Comment: Please check error log. Is it like `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Post without an ID` or `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find User with 'id'=` ?

Comment: Can you post the url you have in the address bar?

Comment: @ray so it's `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PostsController#show` and then `Couldn't find Post with 'id'=index`.

Comment: @iGian http://localhost:3000/posts/index

Comment: @iGian that;s all I get in the console window where I have `rails s` running:

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Post with 'id'=index):app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:16:in show' Started GET "/posts/index" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-12-29 13:53:08 +0100 Processing by PostsController#show as HTML  Parameters: {"id"=>"index"}  Post Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 0], ["LIMIT", 1]]

Completed 404 Not Found in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)`

Comment: for some reason I can't really format the text

Comment: @AleksanderJess URLs that are in the style `/posts/something` are for showing a single post with an id of "something". So here `index` is being interpreted as an ID. For the index action try just `http://localhost:3000/posts` - or if you're seeing the error when clicking on a link from somewhere else in your app then share the `link_to` that you're using.

Comment: My bad. Change the url to  `localhost:3000/posts/1` (or, instead of 1 use the ID of the last post). What are you getting? Also, instead of index.html.erb, please post in your question the content of  `show.html.erb`.

Comment: "...so I changed `params[:id]` to `params[:title]`.." Rollback to `@post = Post.find(params[:id])`

Answer (score 1):

Can you post the error that you are getting.

Just a wild guess, the issue could be in this line

```
<%= link_to post.title, post%>
```

If so, change it to

```
<%= link_to post.title, post_path(post) %>
```

Comment: Sure, the error is "ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PostsController#show" and then below "Couldn't find Post with 'id'=index"

Btw that change you suggested did not help :(

Answer (score 0):

Just starting out and even now I have found that in development the gem BetterErrors https://github.com/BetterErrors/better_errors gives you a great way to debug errors live, maybe you can install this gem and give it a try it will give you better error pages and the ability to see different vars live.

also, it looks like there the problem should be in your

```
<%= link_to post.title, post %>
```

it definitely needs to look something like this

```
<%= link_to(post.title, post_path(post)) %>
```

or

```
<%= link_to post.tilte, post_path(post) %>
```

if this does not work you need to look at your routes and see if you have the route for the show page defined.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I forgot about a basic thing.

After adding `get 'posts/index` in `routes.rb` everything works.